# append pandas data frames in columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I searching for a way to append data frames in new columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([])
perf = [650, 875, 400, 200, 630, 950, 850, 800]

for _ in range(0,8):
    perf = [650+i, 875+i, 400+i, 200+i, 630+i, 950+i, 850+i, 800+i] #perf is independent of i, it's just to show that i have 8 different list 
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Pp': [i for i in perf]}))
print(df)
     Pp
0   650
1   875
2   400
3   200
4   630
..  ...
3   207
4   637
5   957
6   857
7   807
```

64 rows x 1 column but I searching for a way to get 8 rows x 8 columns

```
     Pp   Pp   Pp
0   650  651  ...
1   875  876  ...
2   400  401  ...
3   200  201  ...
4   630  631  ...
..  ...  ...  ...
```

Comment: User `merge` or `concat(..., axis=1)` instead of `append`?

Comment: both give errors concat: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'

Comment: `df = pd.concat((df, other_df), axis=1)`.

Comment: I need to use for loop, I don't have other dfs. this is a simple form of the code I have, so perf changes too and it gives me the output in rows as shown above.

Comment: I edited the question to show what I am searching for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame([])
for i in range(0,8):
    df['Pp'+str(i)] = [random.randint(100, 1000) for val in perf ]

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Pp0  Pp1  Pp2  Pp3  Pp4  Pp5  Pp6  Pp7
0  963  394  165  750  918  687  637  164
1  642  217  154  455  173  807  995  649
2  508  399  833  853  686  834  529  992
3  688  178  328  101  469  559  455  844
4  145  113  416  927  503  882  725  326
5  171  548  394  952  459  725  460  625
6  189  129  136  541  280  131  956  356
7  906  562  779  773  412  423  429  769
```

Comment: not what I am searching for, I edited the question to show what I am searching for

Comment: perf is independent of i, it's just to show that I have 8 different lists so what would you do in this case?

Comment: thanks for your help, the lists generated every loop so that doesn't answer my question, anyway thanks

Comment: @MAAHE then what is your question

Comment: I got some ideas from the solutions you offered and it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no need to use a for loop/appending for this - simply pass the list when creating the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
perf = [650, 875, 400, 200, 630, 950, 850, 800]
df = pd.DataFrame(perf)
```

Then to create the other 7 columns, simply create a new column using the list:

```
df["1"] = perf
df["2"] = perf
```

and so on. Hope this helps!

Comment: Agreed, concat is more a more efficient way to do it